# What is an attached event?

Tags: wpf

I am learning WPF, and I've run into a term called "Attached Event". I have not been able to find a good resource that isn't confusing.

Can anyone tell me what an attached event is and what it does?

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613550.aspx). Make sure you read the prerequisite articles (routed events and XAML). You may also want to look at the whole [WPF events series](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753115.aspx) in MSDN.

I suspect you'll find that if you start from the basics, you'll be able to work up to attached events without too much hassle.

You may also want to read up on [attached properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011.aspx) if you're unfamiliar with them.

If you don't find these helpful, it would be useful if you could give details about which bit you find confusing.